# Jquery get wrong div's width in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have asp.net mvc4 project where I have bootstrap for markup and jquery for client side work.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 container" id="cont">
    <div class="row overlay_container" id="overlayCont">
        <div class="col-md-12 background" id="bg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text" id="txt">
            <h1>This is a test!</h1>
            This is also a test!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/5.jpg" id="porfolioImage" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
        var wdth = $("#porfolioImage").width();
        alert(wdth);
        var hgth = $("#porfolioImage").height();
        alert(hgth);
        $("#overlayCont").width(wdth).height(hgth);
        $("#bg").width(wdth).height(hgth);
```

When hit alert it return wdth = 382 and hgth = 382, but after replace elements I have the following line

```
[<div class=​"col-md-12 background" id=​"bg" style=​"width:​ 412px;​ height:​ 382px;​">​</div>​]
```

And I dont know why it insert 412 instead of 382. But I need 382. Any ideas where is my mistake?

Comment: Width also includes the padding.

Comment: Minus the padding from the total width or simply remove the padding for the div.

Comment: @Anup I suppose that. But why is it alert width and height as 382?

Comment: Coz Width of #porfolioImage is indeed 382. #overlayCont is adding the padding for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#bg").width(wdth).height(hgth);
```

bg width doesn't include padding

col-md-12 has a padding-left: 15px & padding-right: 15px.

Your img width is 382px + 15px + 15px = 412px

Comment: I was try var wdth = $("#porfolioImage").innerWidth();
                var hgth = $("#porfolioImage").innerHeight();
                $("#overlayCont").width(wdth - $("#porfolioImage").css('padding-left') - $("#porfolioImage").css('padding-right')).height(hgth);
                $("#bg").width(wdth - $("#porfolioImage").css('padding-left') - $("#porfolioImage").css('padding-right')).height(hgth); but the same 412px

Comment: You need to remove the padding from css: `#bg{ padding:0; }` or set it with jq: `$('#bg').css('padding',0);

Comment: Padding is coming from `.col-md-12` which is a prebuilt bootstrap class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because bootstrap or you set in css `box-sizing`, like:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

with this setting `.width()` set the width of the element + padding and borders size.

To prevent this behavior without change CSS, i think you simply use `.css()` instead of `.width()` and `.heigth()`, so this:

```
$("#overlayCont").width(wdth).height(hgth);
$("#bg").width(wdth).height(hgth);
```

change in:

```
$("#overlayCont").css({height:hgth, width:wdth});
$("#bg").css({height:hgth, width:wdth});
```

or, min version:

```
$("#overlayCont,#bg").css({height:hgth, width:wdth});
```

`.css("width")`,`.css("width",number)` return and get the css style (ignore padding, border and, box-sizing setting)

`.width()` has a particular behavior dipends to css settings see http://api.jquery.com/width/ for more information.

or the console in my jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyfr5/1/

i hope it can help you to understand.
Bye